# Ошибка "nohup ignoring input and redirecting stderr to stdout"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix

Пытаюсь запустить какой-либо процесс в фоновом режиме и переадресовать вывод в файл. Пробовал `nohup top > list.txt` и т.д., но всегда выводится ошибка:

> nohup: ignoring input and redirecting stderr to stdout

Заранее благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Надо отвязать `top` от терминала и перенаправить поток вывода ошибок.

```
nohup top -bn 1 > list.txt 2>&1
```

Аргументы:
`-b` програма не будет привязана к вводу
`-n 1` завершится после первого цикла (если это нужно)